# Multiple steps in fuelux wizard with form

Tags: forms, fuelux

I am using fuelux wizard component with 3 steps. On each step there are few inputs. I want to submit the inputs to controller at the end of step3. Should I use one form on each step or a single form spanned across all the steps? If one form for each step, how can I consolidate the forms data together while submitting at step3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one form for all three steps.  Check out this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yu4qeqs0/1/

Just make sure `<div class='step-content'>...</div>` is within the form.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!